# ASP listview format price string with ',' seperator

Tags: asp.net, string, string-formatting

I have asp.net website with `listview`. one of the columns is product price.I want to add seperation **','** to the price.

If in the database the price is **1250** I want the `listview` to show **1,250**. The price field is `string` type.

I tried the following but i get 1250 with no separator:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price","{0:n0}")%>'/>

 <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:n0}", Eval("price"))%>'/>
```

Comment: Please try this : `lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", (object)total);` Here `total` contains the value . In your case 1250

Comment: Maybe because price is a string and not a numeric type. It if its a numeric type like `decimal` or `int` it works: `string.Format("{0:N0}",1250)`

Comment: i dont want to do it from code behind but fron the listview item if it is possible.

Comment: Try this  : `Text='<%# Eval("price","{0:#,###,###.##}") %>`

Comment: Tim you right. is there any way to do it with string?

Comment: Abhishek , it doesn't work...

Comment: This : `Text='<%# String.Format("0:C", Eval("price")) %>'` ??

Comment: What is the data type of price in your database ?

Comment: @user281812: the best way is to change your table, it should be a `decimal`. If you can't do that parse it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToInt64(Eval("price")))%>'/>
```